# .cpp error: no match for 'operator<' in 'std::cerr < "Converting file \""'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, nmea

I'm trying to execute this code [nmea2kml.cpp](http://read.pudn.com/downloads150/sourcecode/comm/651136/NmeaConverter.cpp__.htm)

but I keep getting the following errors. Also the program has command line parameters `-f path  Read file at given path (e.g. /some/where/nmea.txt)` What should I change to run the program? Am I getting the error due to a compiler problem? coz I've messed up with adding cygwin, MinGW compilers to eclipse!! I know the program is correct. Others have used it and got the results.(http://julien.cayzac.name/code/gps/)

Error

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\nmea.o ..\src\nmea.cpp
..\src\nmea.cpp: In function `int main(int, char**)':
..\src\nmea.cpp:195: error: no match for 'operator<' in 'std::cerr < "Converting file \""'
..\src\nmea.cpp:195: note: candidates are: operator<(const char*, const char*) <built-in>
..\src\nmea.cpp:195: note:                 operator<(void*, void*) <built-in>
..\src\nmea.cpp:336: error: no match for 'operator<' in 'std::cout < "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>"'
..\src\nmea.cpp:336: note: candidates are: operator<(const char*, const char*) <built-in>
..\src\nmea.cpp:336: note:                 operator<(void*, void*) <built-in>
..\src\nmea.cpp:336: error: `std::endl(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&)' cannot appear in a constant-expression
..\src\nmea.cpp:355: error: parse error in template argument list
..\src\nmea.cpp:336: error: `endl<<expression error> >' cannot appear in a constant-expression
..\src\nmea.cpp:406: error: parse error in template argument list
..\src\nmea.cpp:336: error: `endl<<expression error> >' cannot appear in a constant-expression
..\src\nmea.cpp:406: error: parse error in template argument list
..\src\nmea.cpp:336: error: `endl<<expression error> >' cannot appear in a constant-expression
..\src\nmea.cpp:406: error: parse error in template argument list
..\src\nmea.cpp:406: error: expected `;' before '}' token
..\src\nmea.cpp:193: warning: unused variable 'outfile'
Build error occurred, build is stopped
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have written `std::cerr < "..."` (the `<` operator) where you meant to write `std::cerr << "..."` (the `<<` operator).

Comment: I tried it! but it shows..
In function `int main(int, char**)':|
error: no match for 'operator<' in 'std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>](((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)(+(+std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>](((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)(+(+std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
..main.cpp|347|error: `filename' cannot appear in a constant-expression|
..main.cpp|347|error: `std::endl(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&)' cannot appear in a constant-expression|

Answer (score 1):

Try using the bit-shift "<<" instead of the less-than "<" operator with your ostreams:

```
std::cerr << "Converting file \"";
```

Comment: Isn't it an I/O operator? :-)

Comment: You really shouldn't be referring to "<<" as "bit-shift"

Comment: Actually, a "bit-shift" operator is _exactly_ what this "IO" operator is. As a matter of convention in C++, the bit-shift operators are overloaded and used (and abused) with file/input/output/etc. streams. You are correct in stating, however, that it is confusing for me to use that term with someone unfamiliar with the language.

Answer (score 1):

No, the code as shown is not correct.  You perform output with `std::cout << ...`, not `std::cout < ...`.  Probably some HTML conversion messed it up.